# Error al migrar de vuetify 1.5.16 a 2.0.4

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuetify

Actualice vuetify de la version 1.5.16 a la 2.0.4 pero me da este error

"Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option."

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi importe vuetify, pero aun asi, me sigue dando error

Comment: Te dice que componentes fallan? Si estas usando listas, `v-list-tile` pasa a ser `v-list-item`

Answer (score 0):

El principal problema es que Vuetify v1 funciona bajo el preprocesador Stylus, y en la v2 funciona bajo el preprocesador SASS, y personalmente no recominedo migrar a v2 si es que es un proyecto demasiado avanzado y peor aun si tiene componentes Vuetify personalizados.